# Selecting a specific div within a parent div based on event (hover)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

So, I have a parent div, with 7 child divs. Each one of those 7 divs is a container that will be toggled on a hover or a click. How can I attach the event to one of the 7 divs so that only its contents display? Right now if I hover, the content of all divs is displayed. I need to hover and only display the contents of the hovered div.

```
$('div#HoldsAll').on('hover', function(){
$('div.none').show();
});

<div id="HoldsAll">

<div class="none">
<p>A hover over this parent div should display only this</p>
<p>and this</p>
<p>and this too</p>
</div>
<div class="none">
<p>This should remain hidden</p>
</div>
<div class="none">
<p>This should remain hidden, too</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show your existing jQuery code.

Comment: @navarro try updated solution.

Answer (score 1):

you should use only one unique id for one unique element, use `class="none"`:

if the content of div with class of none is hidden there in no element to hover on, try this:
CSS:

```
.none p {display: none;}
span {color: red}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="HoldsAll">

<div class="none">
 <span>show</span>    
 <p>A hover over this parent div should display only this</p>
 <p>and this</p>
 <p>and this too</p>
 </div>

 <div class="none">
 <span>show</span>    
 <p>This should remain hidden</p>
 </div>

 <div class="none">
 <span>show</span>    
 <p>This should remain hidden, too</p>
 </div>

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
 $(function () {            
   $('.none').hover(function () {
      $(this).find("p").show();
   }, function () {
      $(this).find("p").hide();
   });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/faNtu/

Comment: This wont work based on the simple fact that if the divs regardless of id or class are hidden the user cannot hover over the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate IDs (`id="none"`), which is not allowed and may lead to unexpected behaviour, such as what you are seeing here.

Comment: You can update or delete your answer because someone can downvote your question as there are no duplicated IDs after the questioner updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need something to hover over to make it work, so `.none` will need to have an actual size for you to get your little mousepointer thingy over it, but something like this maybe:

```
$('.none', '#HoldsAll').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $('p', this).show();
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $('p', this).hide();    
    }
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/JDYmj/1/)

Comment: So, if .none has a CSS rule display:none, the event will not apply? If so, should I change the CSS and use .hide so that I can then use .show or .toggle? My main problem is that the triggering action (hover, click over a div) takes place within a div that is a few divs in and out and away from the event target. So I have to get out of a div, find the target div, apply the event. It's kicked my ass, but then again, I'm no ninja.